# How to use function switchVisible by class name?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use pure JavaScript using the function switchVisible. I currently have it working using getElementById, but I have more than one element I want to show and hide when a button is clicked.

Right now my javascript looks like

```
function switchVisible() {
    if (document.getElementById('locked')) {
        if (document.getElementById('locked').style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('locked').style.display = 'inline-block';
            document.getElementById('unlocked').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('locked').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('unlocked').style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }
}
```

CSS

```
#unlocked {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="edit-invoice" type="button" value="Edit Invoice" onclick="switchVisible();" />

<p id="locked" class="locked">anexample.pdf</p>
<input id="unlocked" class="unlocked" type="text" placeholder="anexample.pdf">
```

This works so far, but it can only target one element because it is by Id. How could I take this script and change it so I can target elements by class name so I can hide and show multiple elements on button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target multiple elements by class name

```js
function switchVisible() {

  // Get locked and unlocked elements by class name
  let lockedElems = document.querySelectorAll(".locked");
  let unlockedElems = document.querySelectorAll(".unlocked");

  // Loop through locked elements
  Array.prototype.map.call(lockedElems, function(locked, index) {
  
    // Get current unlocked element
    let unlocked = unlockedElems[index];
    
    // Do your thing
    if (locked) {
      if (locked.style.display == "none") {
        locked.style.display = "inline-block";
        unlocked.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        locked.style.display = "none";
        unlocked.style.display = "inline-block";
      }
    }
    
  });
}
```

```css
.unlocked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="edit-invoice" type="button" value="Edit Invoice" onclick="switchVisible()" />

<p class="locked">anexample.pdf</p>
<input class="unlocked" type="text" placeholder="anexample.pdf">

<p class="locked">anexample.pdf</p>
<input class="unlocked" type="text" placeholder="anexample.pdf">

<p class="locked">anexample.pdf</p>
<input class="unlocked" type="text" placeholder="anexample.pdf">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementsByClassName` and loop over the results.

```
function switchVisible() {
    var locked = getElementsByClassName('locked');
    for (var i = 0; i < locked.length; i++) {
        if (locked[i].style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('locked').style.display = 'inline-block';
            locked[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            locked[i].style.display = 'none';
            locked[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }
}
```